# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{{\int_0^{x^2 } {\frac{{dt}}{{\sqrt[5]{{t^2 + 6}}}}} }}{{x^2 }}$

Tags: integration, limits

> Evaluate the limit $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\displaystyle{\int\limits_0^{x^2 } {\frac{{\mathrm dt}}{{\sqrt[5]{{t^2  + 6}}}}} }}{{x^2 }}.$$

I have a real big limit problem here. I have no idea how to solve it. This one is like a hybrid between Limit and Integral (sorry for my English). There are also two variables, $x$, and $t$. Can you explain the method used and the steps? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: yeah, i do know it

Comment: Ok, then by the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule, $\frac{d}{{dx}}\int_0^{x^2 } {f(t)dt}  = 2xf(x^2 )$. Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you, i can finish this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Do **not** use l'Hospital's rule, it does not apply here, it is a circular argument. The expression is just a difference quotient
$$
\frac{F(x^2)-F(0)}{x^2-0}
$$
for a primitite $F$ with $F'(t)=\frac1{\sqrt[5]{6+t^2}}$.

The limit of the difference quotient is already the differential quotient or derivative $F'(0)=\frac1{\sqrt[5]6}$, there is no need to involve circular arguments.

---

Or put another way, by the integral mean value theorem
$$
\int_0^{x^2}\frac1{\sqrt[5]{6+t^2}}\,dt=(x^2-0)\frac1{\sqrt[5]{6+c^2}}
$$
for some $0<c<x^2$. In the limit, $c$ converges to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Since it resembles the indeterminate form $0/0$, use L'Hopital's rule, and use Differentiation under the Integral Sign to differentiate the integral expression in the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use L'Hôpital's rule, or you can just note that the integrand $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[5]{t^2+6}}$ tends to the constant $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[5] 6}$ as $t\to 0$. So the integral is equal to $\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt[5] 6}+o(x^2)$.